# Syntax error running BLAST online with Biopython

Tags: python, biopython, blast

I am trying to build a script to compare my fasta files from pyrosequencing with the nucleotide GenBank database following the Biopython Tutorial and Cookbook ([Chapter 7](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc83)).

While the process is running, the prompt shows the following message:

```
result_handle=NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", record.seq)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And I do not know what the problem is, or how to fix it. I probably have later errors in my script. But now, I cannot continue woking with it.

Comment: You most likely have an unclosed parens or similar from a previous line. Can you show the relative snippet that contains the `result_handle` line?

Comment: record=SeqIO.read(open("/Users/imac/Desktop/sinchimeras_1.fasta", format="fasta")

result_handle=NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", record.seq)

archivo1=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/bacsoilpia0_otu.xml", "w")
archivo1.write(result_handle.read())

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippet you gave, you just need to close the parenthesis block of your `open` command- `format` is a parameter that's passed to `SeqIO.read`, not `open`.

```
record=SeqIO.read(open("/Users/imac/Desktop/sinchimeras_1.fasta"), # close parens
    format="fasta")
result_handle=NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", record.seq)
archivo1=open("/Users/imac/Desktop/bacsoilpia0_otu.xml", "w")
archivo1.write(result_handle.read())
```